# How do I fix this error for my Export Custom Job?

Tags: java, maven, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to retrieve text messages from 2016 until now. The code is only 26 lines. Here it is:

```
import java.lang.*;
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.bulkexports.v1.export.ExportCustomJob;

public class twilio_export {
    // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
    // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "my account SID";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "my auth token";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Twilio Export Starting");
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        ExportCustomJob exportCustomJob = ExportCustomJob.creator(
                "Messages",
                "my start date",
                "my end date",
                "Export1")
            .setEmail("my email")
            .create();

        System.out.println(exportCustomJob.getFriendlyName());
    }
}
```

When I run the code (in Eclipse), I am asked to choose a main class. When I choose my main class, I get these errors:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClientBuilder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:141)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.buildRestClient(Twilio.java:204)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:180)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
    at twilio_messages.twilio_export.main(twilio_export.java:22)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No class provided, and an appropriate one cannot be found.
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.callerClass(LogManager.java:571)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:596)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:583)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.<clinit>(TwilioRestClient.java:28)
    ...5 more
```

When I use the class `org.apache.logging.log4j.core` as my main class, I get the output `null null`.

Additionally, I did input this dependency into the Maven project's pom.xml file (but I'm not sure if I put it in the correct place):

```
<dependency>

<groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>

<artifactId>twilio</artifactId>

<version>8.5.1</version>

</dependency>
```

I have tried running this project as a Maven project in Eclipse and as a general project; both provide the same errors.

Does anyone know how I can fix this error, or have you experienced it in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not a Java programmer, but I believe that Java class names must start with a capital letter and use Pascal case.

So your class should be called:

```java
public class TwilioExport
```

Perhaps that is why the error says "No class provided, and an appropriate one cannot be found."